# Model derivative translate job giving status code 409 (CONFLICT)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

How to fix status code 409 for translate job.
There are two types of problems I am facing.
 1. Sometimes API returns error status code 409(conflict)
 2. Sometimes it continuously gives in progress status and never completes or fails even.

Once any of the above error occurs, any subsequent job requests starts failing with error code 409.

We are trying node js API for translating job using following code.
let translateResult = derivativesAPI.translate(job, { 'xAdsForce': true }, forgeSvc.requestOAuth2TwoLeggedOBJ(), accessToken);

Answer (score 2):

First try to [delete manifest](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#deleteManifest) for the stuck/pending request file,

If that doesn't works , last option is to [delete](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/BucketsApi.md#deleteBucket) the bucket with pending/stuck translation request and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/), the `409` means:

> The request conflicts with a previous request that is still in progress

As you mentioned a previous request failed, but is pending on our system and causes this conflict. Is that happening consistently with a file? Or random? When it fails (or hangs), what's the manifest? Finally, can you share a problematic URN?

**EDIT**: the file is working now and we'll keep investigating this.

Comment: It is happening consistently with every file.One more thing I noticed is that if I am creating new bucket then it does not give 409 instead it returns urn and after it if we check status of job then it is always in pending state, and never completes.

Here is the urn:"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWx1cGxvYWRidWNrZXRjY3RlY2gtZGV2Mi9QdWJsaXNoT3V0cHV0LmR3Zw"

urn:adsk.objects:os.object:modeluploadbucketcctech-dev2/PublishOutput.dwg

Comment: did a quick test with some DWG files and it seems to work fine, but the URN you provided stopped at 50%, still investigating.